# Can't edit UITextField in IOS5 Simulator

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextfield, xcode4.2

I Checked the "enabled" checkbox  in the "control" section and also enabled "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox in the "View" section on the "Attribute Inspector". But when I run the simulator and try to click in the UITextField, the keyboard wont show up and also there is no sign that it is selected. I am using xcode 4.2.

Comment: Try creating a new project with a single UITextField. If you can activate it, you can be sure it's not an error.

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method works here. To be sure you could try to add

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

and connect it with your text box.

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@ interface ViewController : UIViewController
@ property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@ end  This is how my ViewController.h file looks like. And it still doesn't work. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Give the UITextField a background color so you can be sure it's where you expect it to be and that you are actually tapping inside the field.